# Skip properties in CSS shorthand for padding, margin, etc

Tags: css, shorthand

Is there a way to specify a CSS property is skipped in the shorthand, with padding, border, margin, etc.

Like `padding: <skipped> 1em 2em` instead of:

```
padding-right: 1em
padding-bottom: 2em
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet is to assign the value `auto` though that will only set it to any default [browser] value it may have, I'm guessing that for padding it will reset it to 0 [depending on the element].

Other than that, no.

Comment: Upvoted for parity. I can't see what's wrong with this at all.

Answer (score 7):

The correct way to skip properties is to *not* use shorthand:

```
padding-bottom: 2em;
padding-right: 1em;
```

It's not as elegant as:

```
padding: same 1em 2em same;
```

but it simply doesn't exist in pure CSS. If you use server-side CSS extensions such as LESS or SASS, there may be syntax to do that; if there isn't, it could be added with relative ease.

Comment: There isn't and it's not that simple as you must considder attributes can be added to an element by different classes and LESS/SASS have no knowledge of your HTML. It may seem ugly but `padding-right: 1em; padding-bottom: 2em` is really the only way.

Comment: @sg3s, LESS/SASS would only have to convert `padding: same 1em 2em same;` to `padding-bottom: 2em; padding-right: 1em;`, just like they convert `.foo { .bar {...} .baz {...} }` to `.foo .bar {...}` `.foo .baz {...}`

Comment: hmmm good point... that makes me itch to just submit the needed code to some gitrepos since thats really simple...

Comment: Yes, there's no intrinsic reason why the shorthand can't support it. It does already support this behaviour if you include 3 properties (ie it skips over the fourth one, `padding-left`).

Comment: ... And for that reason, I'd want to use `same 1em 2em`. The `same` on the end is already unnecessary by the existing CSS convention.

Comment: @mahemoff, it doesn't do that behavior if you skip the 4th. `padding: 1em 2em 3em;` is the same as `padding-top: 1em; padding-left: 2em; padding-right: 2em; padding-bottom: 3em;` It reuses the second value for the left *and* right sides, which is different than leaving them alone.

Comment: As a general note, I was on the fence about what to call the keyword (`auto` and `inherit` are obviously taken). Some of the thoughts I had were `as-is`, `same`, `~`, `=`, `@` and `prev`. If anyone does go on to add this feature to a gitrepo, take care to choose the best keyword.

Comment: @zzzzBov True about not skipping 4th, so it's not something done in standard CSS. "as-is" would be clear. I'd want to avoid "same", it comes across like "same as the other attributes here" (at least, if it appeared after the others).

Comment: is there any change since 2012, or still there is no possibility to set skipped values for shorthand?